# How to change all dates on file and preserve them during file move?

Tags: macos, filesystem, file

I would like to change all dates on a file [all four reported by `stat` command].
I cannot find a way to change the "inode last changed" date.
I've tried:

```
touch -t
SetFile -d
SetFile -m
```

but this single date remains unchanged.

Also, is there any way to move file between directories and leave all of the dates intact?
I am moving whole directories, with lots of files inside, so I would prefer to have a single command to do so, if not - I will read the date upfront and set it after the move.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot control`ctime`.`ctime` is set with the creation of the `inode`. `ctime` changes to the `mtime` when you modify a file. `ctime` is set to the current date and time when you modify the `inode metadata`, such as changing `mtime`, file permissions, or renaming a file.

The closest you can come to matching `atime`,`mtime`, and `ctime` would be to`touch` a file which will set all three to the current date and time. But at anytime `ctime` may change, even OS X applications can cause changes to the `inode metadata` without changing the content of a file.

`btime` or `birthtime` will not change when moving files on the same filesystem.

Tools that support preserving file metadata are `ditto`, `pax`, and `cp` with the p option. None of these tools support preserving `birthtime` across filesystems.